# How to get the current logged in user? Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to get the current logged in user to this CreateForm form. Below Im giving my current code, here request.user is not giving me error

> ValueError at /create-post/
> Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: testuser>>": "Post.author" must be a "Author" instance.

models.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   rate = models.IntegerField(default=0)
 
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    overview = models.TextField()
    body_text = RichTextUploadingField(null = True)
    time_upload = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name='author', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'thumbnails')
    publish = models.BooleanField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Categories)
    read = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(null= True, blank= True)
```

Forms.py

```
class CreateForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = [
        'title',
        'overview',
        'body_text',
        'thumbnail',
        'categories',
        'publish',
    ]
```

Views.py

```
def create_post(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CreateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid:
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.author= request.user
        post.save()
        return render(request, 'index.html')
else:
    form = CreateForm()
return render(request, 'create_post.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Reuqest author is not author instance, you should do request.user.author

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, `post.author` expects an `Author` object, not the user. You thus retrieve this with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.author= request.user.author
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'index.html')
    else:
        form = CreateForm()
    return render(request, 'create_post.html', {'form': form})
```

You should also *call* the [**`is_valid()`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_valid), so `form.is_valid()`.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Answer (score 2):

The `author` field on your `Post` model is a foreign key to `Author` model, and not user. You could replace `post.author = request.user` with:

```
if request.user.author:
    post.author = request.user.author
else:
    post.author = Author.objects.create(user=request.user)
```

The answer from Willem works if an Author instance was already created for the User, but will throw an exception if there's no Author object associated with that user.

Comment: Thank you. I just want get the current logged in user only, I don't want to create a new one. As I will modify this one with login decorators.

Comment: This snippet is not for creating a new user, it's for creating an author object to associate with that user in case it was not created before

Comment: @KauêOliveira: this will likely not work since `request.user.author` will raise an `AttributeError` (`RelatedObjectDoesNotExists`) when there is no related `Author` object.

Comment: It won't. It would raise `AttributeError` if we tried to access any attributes on the author, for example `request.user.author.rate`, which is not the case.

Comment: @KauêOliveira: notice that the `OneToOneField` is *reversed*: hence it will *not* return `None`. There has been a lot of dicussion about this, but `.author` will *not* return `None`. See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3016 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610563/django-onetoone-reverse-relation-doesnotexists-when-empty